# Flex Air application: open window on right bottom corner

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am developing a flex air application and i want to it open in right bottom corner as notification..How do i do this.

Thanks
Atul yadav

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project directory in flex builder. Lets say your app name is Test

Go to Test->src
There you should find an Test-app.xml

In that you will find data regarding the width, height, x and y coordinates of the window to be opened.

change the following lines there:

```
<!-- Whether the user can resize the window. Optional. Default true. -->
<resizable>false</resizable>

<!-- The window's initial width in pixels. Optional. -->
<width>200</width>

<!-- The window's initial height in pixels. Optional. -->
<height>300</height>

<!-- The window's initial x position. Optional. -->
<x>800</x>

<!-- The window's initial y position. Optional. -->
<y>600</y>
```

You might have to change the X,Y values according to your screen.

If you just want a popup, you should take a look at the popupmanager class for adobe air.